# Is it possible to temporarily disable non-global zones?

Tags: solaris, zones

I frequently need to install a package on the global zone for a quick test on a development box.

When there are multiple prompts for one package I have to answer them for each zone. If the zone is not running then I need to wait for the zone to start up, answer the prompts, etc.

This is particularly annoying when if I'm getting packages from http://www.sunfreeware.com and using the `pkg-ge`t utility which nicely pulls in dependencies for you.

Can I disable the zones temporarily? I haven't found a way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Just tell pkgadd to install in the global zone only by uncommenting this line in the pkg-get.conf file:

```
PKGADDFLAGS=-G
```

If using pkgadd, add this -G flag to the command line.

If for some reason, you really want to disable all non global zones, a quick (and dirty) way is to move temporarily /etc/zones to /etc/zones.disable.

Comment: Thanks.  I'd read about the -G flag but had forgotten all about it.